# Using jquery to access a nested json array

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to access a nested JSON array from a jquery $.each but I am not able to.  Here's my code:

```js
console.log("Entered Script");
$.getJSON('json/insuranceData.json', function(data) {
  $.each(data.insuranceReport, function(i, f) {
    console.log("first $.each part of Script");
    $.each(data.insuranceReport.dataFilePaths, function(i, g) {
      console.log("second $.each part of Script");
      var dataFile = "?dataTablePath=" + g.path + "&"
      console.log(g.path);
      if (g == null) {
        console.log("script broke here")
        return false; // Break
      }
    });
    var divData = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href='employees/index.html" + f.dataFile + "insuranceName=" + f.insuranceName + "'>" + f.insuranceName + "</a>" + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + f.employeeCost + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.employerCost + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.totalCost + "</td>" + "</tr>"
    $(divData).appendTo("#dataTable tbody");
  });
});
console.log("script comnpleted.");
```

I want to access dataFilePaths array which is nested in insuranceReport but it doesn't seem to want to work.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: From your code, it's clear that you're stumbling about in the dark with a `console.log` torch. Instead, *turn on the lights* using the debugger built into your browser.

Comment: I've taken a guess below, but it would help a **lot** if we could see the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to access dataFilePaths array which is nested in insuranceReport

Then you want `f.dataFilePaths`, not `data.insuranceReport.dataFilePaths`:

```
$.getJSON('json/insuranceData.json', function(data) {
  $.each(data.insuranceReport, function(i, f) {
    //                                     ^------------ will refer
    console.log("first $.each part of Script");       // to each entry
    $.each(f.dataFilePaths, function(i, g) {          // in data.insuranceReport
    //     ^----- So use it here
```

Comment: Got it.  That worked.  Thanks!